# Null exception while setting "textfont" property of AcroFields in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

While changing font of an AcroForm field in an existing PDF document using iTextSharp, I'm encountering a null-pointer exception at the line where I'm setting the 'textfont' property.
I'm able to set the value of the field using the same code though.
I've followed the following example to create my code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748901/custom-font-not-getting-applied-on-existing-pdf-template-itextsharppdfstamper

My stack trace looks like this:

```
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.SaveColor(BaseColor color, Boolean fill)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.SetRGBColorFill(Int32 red, Int32 green, Int32 blue)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor value)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(String field, String name, Object value, Int32[] inst)
at iTextSharpUsage.Utilities.UpdateFontUsingEmbededFont(String inputPdf, String resultPdf) in D:\iTextSharpUsage\iTextSharpUsage\iTextSharpUsage\Utilities.cs:line 229
```

My code looks like this:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
string fontsfolder = @"D:\Airmole\airmole.ttf";
var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(resultPdf, FileMode.Create));
BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.CreateFont();
AcroFields af = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
List<BaseFont> list = new List<BaseFont>();
list.Add(customfont);
iTextSharp.text.Font bold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(customfont, 13,0,BaseColor.BLACK);
af.SubstitutionFonts = list;
foreach (var field in af.Fields)
{
    af.SetField(field.Key, "s");
    //this line works fine
    bool isSuccess = pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "textcolor ", BaseColor.BLACK , null);
    //the line bellow throws a null pointer exception
    bool isSucces1s = pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "textfont", customfont, null);
}
```

Do I have to add some more code for this to work ??

A quick update here... i got the problem solved thanks to comments posted by @Bruno, this functinality works fine in version 5.3.3.

Comment: It's a bug that was introduced in iText 5.3.4 or 5.3.5. I discovered and fixed it about three hours ago. Either use a slightly older version of iTextSharp or wait until the next release (scheduled for February 14th).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bruno. I'll try with older version and update the post :)

Comment: +1 for your comment. Note that I fixed the problem on the Java-side. All info you could give on the version where the bug was introduced on the C#-side is welcome!

Comment: Hey @BrunoLowagie, Thanks for the help,  I got it working with version 5.3.3, but when I try to flatten the file using the code  pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;  the flattened PDF only has data in the new field created using iTextSharp, where as other fields remain blank even if there is data in them

Comment: I'd need to see the PDF to know what happens. Are you sure you have an AcroForm document (as opposed to an XFA form)? Are you sure the text fits the rectangle (changing the fontsize to 0 can help)? Are you sure the visibility settings are right? I can't answer your question if you don't answer mine.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, and thanks again for the prompt reply, Well I check the original PDF using the code 
'code' 
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
PdfObject xObject = XfaForm.GetXfaObject(pdfReader); 
'code' 
as it turns out there are no XfaObjects in the code and all the fields I'm getting are Acro.

Comment: I also modified my above code by adding
'code'
bool set = pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "textsize", 8.0f, null);
bool set1 = pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "setfflags",PdfFormField.FLAGS_PRINT, null);
bool set2 = pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
'code'So that my whole text is inside my fields, its readonly and its visible.But still existing filed values are not getting printed,but the value of field created using iTextSharp is  printed after flattening.So,is there anything else I can try

Comment: (PS.. Was able to code the above thanks to your previous posts. Please keep up the wonderful work :)
Unfortunately sharing of the PDF is not  possible due to policies :( )

Comment: Take a look at how you set the text size and compare with my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748901/custom-font-not-getting-applied-on-existing-pdf-template-itextsharppdfstamper I think the text isn't shown because the text size isn't set properly (that's an educated guess without seeing the PDF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't share the PDF, I did some tests with a number of PDFs I created. I found a case where prefilled fields in a form where the `/NeedAppearances` setting was *true*, weren't flattened (they just came out as empty fields). I guess I always worked with forms where `/NeedAppearances` was *false* (which is the default) and therefore never encountered the problem. I fixed this: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5682/

The fix will be in the next release.